# git-subtree: several occurrences of a subproject

Tags: git, git-subtree

Suppose that I have a project A, a project B that depends on A, and a project C that depends on A and B.

I use git-subtree for dealing with subprojects; the project C contains a subtree corresponding to project A, and another subtree for project B; the last has a subtree for it's own copy of project A.

I got stuck with the following problem: calling something like `git merge -s subtree A/master` in C causes the B/A be updated (the A that lies inside B subproject), not the A that is a direct dependency of C. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?

Note that I consider having only one A in the whole tree (and using B/A in C) a bad idea: I do not want to depend on the fact, that B depends on A; there can also be version issues and so on.